# Cannot run flask app via guniocorn on clean environment

Tags: flask, gunicorn

I have this flask app code to start it:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
.
.
.
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8444) # starts the web app at port 8444
```

I am trying to run it via gunicorn based on few tutorials:

```
gunicorn -b :5001 app:app
```

And I am getting following error:

```
[2023-07-03 09:20:53 +0200] [62647] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2023-07-03 09:20:53 +0200] [62647] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5001 (62647)
[2023-07-03 09:20:53 +0200] [62647] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-07-03 09:20:53 +0200] [62648] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 62648
 * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://192.168.0.166:8444/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
[2023-07-03 09:20:55 +0200] [62649] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2023-07-03 09:20:55 +0200] [62649] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('', 5001)
[2023-07-03 09:20:55 +0200] [62649] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
```

In every solution which I found people were talking about killing processes binded to the following ports but there are no such processes in my case. I've actually originally tried to run it on docker but I failed and there are deffinetelly nothing on those ports on docker. I was trying with different ports as well here.

For me it looks like gunicorn starts listening before app is starting and it cannot bind it then.